# What’s the best way to invoke a second Mono without losing the result of the first?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have code that needs to interact with two reactive dependencies - saving to a database and publishing to a stream, each of which return `Mono` instances. After this, I need to do some more processing - all using the original object I started with, something like this:

```
val myObject = Mono.just(“thing”);
myObject.flatMap(repository::save)
        .flatMap(stream::publish)
        .map(obj -> moreProcessing(obj));
```

But the problem is, `repository.save` doesn’t return a `Mono` of the object I’m interested in and neither does `stream.publish`.

I can achieve what I want with something like:

```
myObject.flatMap(obj -> repository.save(obj).then(Mono.just(obj))
        .flatMap(obj -> stream.publish(obj).then(Mono.just(obj))
        .map(obj -> moreProcessing(obj));
```

i.e. mapping to the dependency functions just to get their behaviour and then mapping straight back again, but this seems odd - like I might be missing some better way to use the API which doesn’t give the hint that I’m mapping between types, because that’s not what I’m using `flatMap` for, really.

I can also go with something like:

```
myObject.flatMap(obj ->
            repository.save(obj)
                .flatMap(x -> publisher.stream(obj))
                .map(x -> moreProcessing(obj)));
```

but that doesn’t seem like a great way to go either, as it’s going to lead to hard-to-maintain code in even relatively simple cases.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it using code bellow. I think it is important not to get lost in method chaining at all cost. As it very easy to overengeener creating the constructions that are hard to read.

```
@Test
public void mergeMonos(){
    Mono<String> myObject = Mono.just("my object");
    Mono<String> savedToDB = saveToDb(myObject);
    Mono<String> savedToStream = saveToStream(myObject);


    //if you need to wait for the first two to complete
    Flux.concat(savedToDB, savedToStream, myObject)
            .last()
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    //if you don't need to wait for the db and stream
    Flux.merge(savedToDB, savedToStream, myObject)
            .last()
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

private Mono<String> saveToStream(Mono<String> myObject) {
    return myObject.map(t-> "saved to stream");
}

private Mono<String> saveToDb(Mono<String> myObject) {
    return myObject.map(t-> "saved to db");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try a `thipWhen`? It behaves like you wish with the only restriction, that it completes immediatly, if the result of the `rightGenerator` is empty (there is no next signal). So you need to either return an `Optional` or use `thenReturn` or `switchIfEmpty`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid losing any of your references could be something like:

```
Mono<User> monoUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                                .filter(u -> validatePassword(pass, u.getPassword()));

Mono<Clinic> monoClinic = monoUser.flatMap(u -> clinicRepository.findByUserId(u.getId()));
        
return Mono.zip(monoUser, monoClinic, (u,c) -> proccess(u, c));
```

The first Mono return an user, the second mono is using the user returned by the first Mono and return a clinic, and the returned mono (third mono) is using the output of the first mono and the output of the second mono to create a different object (returned by proccess method that is using the user and the clinic)